# How to solve [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ] for writeFile()

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, writefile

this function should create a file, my script include 20 of them in a sequence

```
const fs     = require('fs');

createFile( file.name + files.create_meta, blueprint.create_meta, data )
```

this function create the content

```
function createFile(filePath, blueprintPath, data) {
   const blueprint = fs.readFileSync(blueprintPath, 'utf8');
   const content = template(blueprint, {
     email: data.email,
     name: data.name,
     date: data.date,
   })

  fs.writeFile(filePath, content, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

sometime it work, but often i get an this error message:

```
 [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ]
```

If this message appear, the file was not created because the files not exist at the beginning and the error means that the function cannot find a file in this path.

how can i guarantee that my function create the files?

Comment: Can you update the question to show how you have included 20 of them in a sequence?

Answer (score 0):

You can update `createFile` function like this.

```
const fs = require("fs");

function createFile(filePath, blueprintPath, data) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(blueprintPath)) {
    throw new Error(blueprintPath + " does not exist");
  }
  const blueprint = fs.readFileSync(blueprintPath, "utf8");
  const content = template(blueprint, {
    email: data.email,
    name: data.name,
    date: data.date
  });

  // creates an empty file if doesn't exist
  fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(filePath, "w"));
  fs.writeFile(filePath, content, function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
}

try {
  // call your function in try-catch
  createFile("./test.txt", "testtest", "test");
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message);
}
```